# Exporting CSV from ui-grid with cell display rather than the source value

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a table done with ui-grid and this table has a column with cellFilter definition like this:

```
  { field: 'company', cellFilter: 'mapCompany:row.grid.appScope.companyCatalog' }
```

My gridMenu custom item is configured like this:

```
gridMenuCustomItems: [
        {
            title:'Custom Export',
            action: function ($event) {

              var exportData = uiGridExporterService.getData(this.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, true);

              var csvContent = uiGridExporterService.formatAsCsv([], exportData, this.grid.options.exporterCsvColumnSeparator);

              uiGridExporterService.downloadFile (this.grid.options.exporterCsvFilename, csvContent, this.grid.options.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);

            },
            order:0
        } 
    ]
```

The table is displayed correctly, but when I try to export to CSV, the Company column is exported with empty value. Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LNj7TImWQg8G7mmXIyAz?p=preview).

Any suggestion will be appretiated

**References**

I did some research and according to [ui-grid Issue #4948](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/pull/4948) it works good when the Company column is filled with an static catalog. Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iunzUmHe0DYFH7EFSTGQ?p=preview) demostrating that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the CSV export to be able to display the cell display value.
My mistake was using row.grid instead of this.grid at the mapCompany cell filter:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'company', cellFilter: 'mapCompany:row.grid.appScope.companyCatalog' }
],
```

The right way to use it is using this:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'company', cellFilter: 'mapCompany:this.grid.appScope.companyCatalog' }
],
```

Here is my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/btiJb94V1GcMGQueAwPd?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there is an export issue when the values in the column are not static, so I [forked your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7MWyFlEq3UkqE5EKMFVg?p=preview) with a solution that creates the company mapping for each data object and adds it as a key-value once you get the company catalog back:

```
 $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs')
   .success(function(data) {

     $scope.companyCatalog = data;
     angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.data, function(item) {
       var compMap = uiGridFactory.getMapCompany(item.company, $scope.companyCatalog);
       item.mappedCo = compMap;
     });
   });
```

I've kept the original company column but made it invisible (rather than overwriting it), so it exports with the rest of the data in the csv. New column defs:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'mappedCo', name: 'Company'},
  { field: 'company', visible: false }
]
```

Also, in the case that you were getting your data from a server, you would have to ensure that the data and the catalog returned before you run the mapping function. This solution may not work in your particular use case; I don't know.

Comment: Hello Adams. Thank you for your suggestion! In my particular case I considered an option similar to this one you propose, but I did not want to create a fake column because I have a lot of grids with the similar problem. If I cannot find a solution in a month, I think I will use this approach.